# Pycharm just works in debug mode in a Qthread project

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, qthread

I have this sample code

```
def initializeData(self):
    # di.CSVImporter(self.configParser.get('SectionOne', 'Path'), sqlbase.engine)
    self.progressBar.setValue(0)
    self.progressBar.setVisible(True)
    initializer = DataCollector()
    self.threadInit = QThread()
    self.threadInit.setObjectName('initThread')
    initializer.moveToThread(self.threadInit)
    # get progress messages from worker:
    initializer.sig_step.connect(self.on_worker_step)
    initializer.sig_done.connect(self.on_worker_done)
    self.sig_abort_workers.connect(initializer.abort)
    self.threadInit.started.connect(initializer.initializeData)
    self.threadInit.start()  # this will emit 'started' and start thread's event loop

@pyqtSlot(int)
def on_worker_step(self, data: int):
    self.progressBar.setValue(data)

@pyqtSlot(int)
def on_worker_done(self, data: int):
    self.progressBar.setVisible(False)

@pyqtSlot(str)
def on_worker_send(self, data: str):
    self.statusBar().showMessage(data)



@pyqtSlot()
def abort_workers(self):
    self.sig_abort_workers.emit()
    # self.thread.quit()
```

When I run it in Debug Mode it works but in release mode it doesn't. Is this because of configuration?

The debug mode configuration is like below:

[image: configurationImage]